# class for wrapping up upload button with select file input

Tags: html, class

I recently downloaded a template to be used for login/signup on my page and am trying to figure out a class that can wrap up the upload button(font awesome icon) and the select file input control for an image.
Here is my code...

```
<html>
<head>
<--//Bootstrap support plugins->
</head>
<body>
<div class="wthree-form bg">
<div class="agileits-2">
<h2>Sign Up Here</h2>
</div>
<form action="signup.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<--These classes make the form look real good by wrapping up the font awesome icon with an input field->
<div class="w3-user">
<span><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i></span>
<input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required="">
</div>
<--Here is my problem->
<div class="w3-? ">
<span><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></span>
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
</div>
<form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The question mark above is what needs a class to make the form wrap the upload icon together with a classy select file control to make it look good thanks...
The other wrap controls  work perfectly well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will fix your problem, but it looks like you need to change your second form tag to a closing form tag.

change

```
<div class="w3-? ">
<span><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></span>
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
</div>
<form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

to

```
<div class="w3-? ">
<span><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></span>
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need class like "w3-user",  something like "w3-file", Thanks for your answer anyways